# Search file by filter with regex

Tags: c#, regex, directory

I need to find a file(s) that begin with the character "prft" the name of this files is "prft0000.140", "prft2100.140", "prft1258.140"... etc. And I need to verify if this file(s) exists in a directory specific. So I have this Regex for find them, but I don't know how write the filter to match.

```
List<string> prftFiles = (new DirectoryInfo(filePath))
                        .GetFiles(".", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        .Where(a => Regex.IsMatch(a.Name, "prft[^*]$"))
                        .Select(fi => fi.Name)
                        .ToList();
```

this not work "prft[^*]$", so,  How is it??

Comment: Why use a RegEx when `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` already has a wildcard search pattern that can do 'starts with'?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not just do `List prftFiles = (new DirectoryInfo(filePath)).GetFiles("prft*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`

Answer (score 1):

This is regex you could use

```
string pattern = @"^(prft\d{4}\.\d{3})$";
```

but you can find files by the wildcard and * like other guys said
if you want exactly math for patter prft 4 digits . 3 digits you should use the regex
because the prft* will find any files with name starts with prft

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to use a Regex here, as the Directory class has a searching mechanism in the pattern you select.

```
Directory.GetFiles("C:\SomeDirectory", "prft*");
```

The `*` widlcard matches to anything.